# Differentiating semantic error, logic error and runtime error

Tags: python, runtime-error, syntax-error

Today, I came across this exam question (This is not totally the same as the exam question but the idea is the same):

```
Which of the following codes is semantic error?

A) a = 'abc' + 123

B) for i in range(5)

C) b = 7/0

D) [i for i in range(10**19)]
```

As I've been taught during the lecture, generally, there are 4 types of errors: Syntax error, Runtime error, Logic error and Semantic error. On this basis, I figure that `C`, which returns ZeroDivisionError, is runtime error, logic error and semantic error. However, `A`, in my opinion, is also semantic error because maybe the programmer wanted to do `a = 'abc' + '123'`.

I know this topic has been brought up a lot, but I'm still so confused and can't spot the difference between these types of errors. If possible, could you give me an answer to the above question and also differentiate these definitions? Thank you in advance!

Comment: According to the lecture, what is the difference between "logic error" and "semantic error"?

Comment: They told me a semantic error means the meaning of the program, so like we mean it but the computer misunderstand, and logic error is because we understand it incorrectly. (I might have misunderstood them somewhere, this is so abstract to me)

Comment: Right. I haven't really heard that definition before but I might say A is the semantic error. You can see what the programmer probably wanted to do, and in some languages it would work, but of course in Python it doesn't.

Comment: A) is also a runtime error; the categories are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: Ikr, the definition of those errors are confusing. Also the A could also be logic error because it could be that the programmer misunderstood the task. And obviously all of them are runtime errors.

Comment: Yeah, if all you have is the code, then anything that relies on guessing the programmer's intention can only be subjective! One side note, dividing by zero in numpy is OK, e.g. `np.array([7]) / 0` gives `array([inf])` without an error. So you could argue that in C, the programmer has a sensible intent but the error comes from using vanilla Python rather than numpy.

Comment: yeh you're right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A semantic error is when a programmer misunderstands how the programming language works and writes code that doesn’t make sense in the context of the language’s rules. The code may be syntactically correct, but it violates the rules or “semantics” of the language. Therefore, the first piece of code is semantic error.

The second piece of code is SyntaxError, the third is RuntimeError, and the last piece of code is either MemoryError or TimeoutError.